# Flexbox not wrapping properly on iOS

Tags: ios, css, flexbox

I have this css: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGypdG/)

```
    * {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        box-sizing:border-box;          
    }
    body,html {
        width:100%; height: 100%;
    }

    .v-field, .v-field-label {
      border: 1px #bcbcbc solid;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }

    .vc-min-200 {
      min-width: 300px;
    }
    .vc-6 {
        width:50%;
    }

    .panel{ 
        border:1px #ccc solid;
    }
    .row {
        outline: 1px #c00 solid;
    }

    form.v-form {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    form.v-form .row.flex {
      margin: 15px 0px;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap:wrap;
    }
    form.v-form .row.flex > div {
      margin: 10px 0px;
      padding: 0px 5px;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      /*flex: 1 1 200px;*/
    }
    form.v-form .v-field, form.v-form .v-field-label {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 6px 12px;
    }
```

The idea is to have a form that has at most 2 columns of 50% width each, but when the window is resized below the minimum width, it should wrap into a single column.

It works great on desktop Chrome and Android, however on iOS (10.0.2) it fails to wrap properly. I've attached a screenshot. 
If I uncomment the `flex: 1 1 200px` line, then it works fine on iOS but produces 3 columns on desktop when the window size allows for it, which is not what I want. Is there a solution that will work on desktop and iOS?

[image: iOS fail screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is related to [this Safari bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136041), where flex basis is ignored when in px and not in percentage. Can you try in percentage and let me know? If I understand it right with flex: 1 1 50%; you get the desired effect.

```
form.v-form .row.flex > div {
  margin: 10px 0px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}
```

Pen [here](http://codepen.io/ksiabani/pen/NRBwKr)

Comment: You are right, I have updated my answer and pen, tested in both iOS 9 and 10